# groovy replaceFirst command not working as expected

Tags: xml, groovy

I am trying to do a simple replaceFirst on a string in groovy but I dont understand why its not working.

```
" <xls:Customer xmlns:xls=\"uri:1\">\n" +
"  <xls:Catalog_ID>1</xls:Catalog_ID>\n" +
"  <xmls:Shop_ID>A</xmls:Shop_ID>\n" +
" </o2020:Customer>".replaceFirst("xmlns:xls=\"uri:1\"","")
```

could someone please advise.

Comment: 1. That's not valid XML.  2. Don't use Regex to parse and change xml

Answer (score 2):

The method call has higher precedence than `+`, so replaceFirst is getting called on only the last substring. It will work if you parenthesize so that the replaceFirst affects the concatenated string:

```
(" <xls:Customer xmlns:xls=\"uri:1\">\n" +
"  <xls:Catalog_ID>1</xls:Catalog_ID>\n" +
"  <xmls:Shop_ID>A</xmls:Shop_ID>\n" +
" </o2020:Customer>").replaceFirst("xmlns:xls=\"uri:1\"","")
```

If you use triple-quotes for the xml string, and single quotes for the replacement regex, then you can fix the precedence problem while also losing the escape characters and newlines:

```
groovy:000> """<xls:Customer xmlns:xls="uri:1">
groovy:001>    <xls:Catalog_ID>1</xls:Catalog_ID>
groovy:002>    <xmls:Shop_ID>A<xmls:Shop_ID>
groovy:003>    </o2020:Customer>""".replaceFirst('xmlns:xls="uri:1"', '')
===> <xls:Customer >
   <xls:Catalog_ID>1</xls:Catalog_ID>
   <xmls:Shop_ID>A<xmls:Shop_ID>
   </o2020:Customer>
```

Either the [triple single-quote](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_triple_single_quoted_string) or the [triple double-quote](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_triple_double_quoted_string) will work here, the difference is that the double-quoted one is a GroovyString that allows interpolation, while the single-quoted one is an ordinary String.

(Using XML APIs is preferable to running regexes on XML, regexes are fast but error-prone, if the document changes to introduce spaces or newlines in the text you're looking for it could break your code. Consider going with [the XML-parsing approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31435176/217324) instead.)

Answer (score 1):

So, converting your invalid XML in the question into what (I hope) you meant to post, you get:

```
def xml = '''<xls:Customer xmlns:xls="uri:1">
             |    <xls:Catalog_ID>1</xls:Catalog_ID>
             |    <xls:Shop_ID>A</xls:Shop_ID>
             |</xls:Customer>'''.stripMargin()
```

Then you can do:

```
import groovy.xml.*

// Read the xml in (ignoring namespaces)
def parsed = new XmlSlurper(false, false)
                  .parseText(xml)

// Remove the attribute
parsed.attributes().remove('xmlns:xls')

// Convert the XML back to a string
def output = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{ mkp.yield parsed }

// print it out
println output
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some parenthese around the whole string

At the moment you are doing this

```
" <xls:Customer xmlns:xls=\"uri:1\">\n" +
"  <xls:Catalog_ID>1</xls:Catalog_ID>\n" +
"  <xmls:Shop_ID>A</xmls:Shop_ID>\n" +
(" </o2020:Customer>".replaceFirst("xmlns:xls=\"uri:1\"",""))
```

I think you want to do something else.